# How do I choose random objects of the same type from a vector array of differing types?

Tags: java, oop, vector

Let's say for example a vector is composed of some objects, one of type rectangle, some of type triangle, and then circles.

```
v = [rectangle, triangle, triangle, circle, circle]
```

The vector's size can change. I can add another circle as so:

```
v.addElement(circle);
```

and..

```
v = [rectangle, triangle, triangle, circle, circle, circle]
```

but each object type is clustered together like above. It can't be like:

```
v = [rectangle, circle, circle, triangle, circle, triangle] //<-- can't be.
```

I know I explained it pretty horrible but hopefully, it's enough to understand my scenario. Now, I want to randomly choose, for example, an object of type circle.

My thought process is to make a separate method that 1, finds the beginning index and 2, find the ending index and then use random functions off of that. Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem of only choosing randomly off of circles?

Comment: The question is why are you using a `Vector` ? I think it seems you want to use a dictionary data structure rather than a sequence..

Comment: When you say random, do you mean that all the types get an equal chance, or do you mean that more common types have a higher change. IE if a pick a random element, is the ratio of `rectangle:triangle:circle` `1:2:3` or `1:1:1`?

Comment: @Dgrin91 I only need circles so it's an equal chance of getting circles but 0 chance of anything else.

Comment: @nachokk yes that would be the best, but I'm using vectors for the simplicity.

Comment: @GigaTocka Wait, what? You want to randomly select a circle? Why not just declare a new circle then?

Comment: i think it's not simple use a vector than a `HashMap` for example, i don't understand what are you talking about when you say "simplicity"

Comment: Isn't `Vector` deprecated?

Comment: @clwhisk Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Collections API:

```
Collections.shuffle(v);
Object random = v.get(0);
```

Comment: It would `shuffle()` the entire vector.

Comment: That would be fine I guess, shuffle then choose the first circle

Answer (score 0):

You should use a hashmap and map the object class as the key and a corresponding array of objects of that class.  You can yse reflection to get the class name and set as the key, then add the object to the array as the value.

Otherwise you can't group similar objects in the array and choose a random object from a set of similar objects in an array of different classes like you asked... Unless you framed your question incorrectly

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do what the poster is asking for.

Comment: Yes I can do it but I'm just looking for a more simpler way. I agree though, a data structure would be best in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a fairly simple random pick problem. All you need to do is generate a random number and get that element -

```
v.get(Random.nextInt(v.size()));
```

Comment: Yes but only the circles can be chosen which makes it a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @GigaTocka Why not just put the circles in a different container?

Comment: @Dgrin31 yea there are a lot of different ways to do this but I'm looking for it to work with one single vector.

Comment: @GigaTocka Yeah... you really gotta rework your data structures here then.

Comment: Even a couple of pointers to traverse the list is a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially use the `implements` keyword to check if an object is of a type (or a subtype of that type), but this is not a very pretty solution.

The best solution would likely be to control read and write access to this vector; basically, if you have specific methods for inserting the different shapes, you can stay in control and always ensure that things are inserted to the right place. At that point, just store two `int`s or such to know where the second and third sections start when choosing.

Although personally, I would just use three separate vectors, if that's possible.